# Angular How to load new component on table row click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

If I have a table populated from my api loaded into the router outlet, how can I load a different component to replace the table with the selected row details? For example if I had a list of equipment in a table, id like to click on one of them to load a component where I have a form that would log details of a fault on that piece of equipment that would be posted to a fault function in the api.

How could this be implemented?

Still learning all of the ropes in angular.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome :) It's better to attach some expected visuals, or flowchart to your question or a code you already tried... That would clarify the question to other users.

Answer (score 0):

Well sounds like conditional rendering, on click get data from clicked row and set showForm to true and showTable to false, then in your html check do the conditional rendering

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do what you asked.

you can use **Routing**, create different routes one for the list page and one for the details page, and add `routerLink="details page path"` on the data row.

I suggest you do the tour of heroes tutorial from angular on the following [URL](https://angular.io/tutorial) if you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Route parameters](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters).

```js
{ path: 'hero/:id', redirectTo: '/superhero/:id' },
```

```html
 <a [routerLink]="['/hero', hero.id]">
   <span class="badge">{{ hero.id }}</span>{{ hero.name }}
</a>
```

You can find the full example [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kekbyeeoxjk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes-routing.module.ts).